# Htaccess Directs to Online When I Want to Work On Localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I changed my localhost server Apache to XAMPP. After then, my project has started to go to online site yusufcode.com(my website link) while I want to work on localhost. Where is the problem? This was the first question.

My second question is my links not works without .php extension on localhost.

Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yusufcode.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: "I changed my localhost server Apache to XAMPP" - XAMPP _is_ Apache - it's what the "A" stands for. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I found the problem. The problem is the localhost port number.

I changed the port number from:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

To this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
```

And all problems has solved. Thanks stackoverflow again. This platform helps me always, even nobody not answered :)

Comment: But that doesn't make sense... if you simply change `80` to `443` in that last rule then on localhost (where you presumably don't have an SSL cert and are accessing the site over HTTP only) then that rule is simply bypassed. But on a live site, where you presumably do have an SSL cert and are accessing the site over HTTPS then it will create a redirect loop and the site won't be accessible?!

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to HTTPS (and www) but only on "live" site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(yusufcode\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle extensionless .php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

There were a number of issues with your original directives that handled the PHP-extensionless URLs... the second `RewriteRule` ran unconditionally. The file check was potentially testing a different file that the one being requested.

---

**UPDATE:** This of course does assume that `.htaccess` overrides are enabled in the server config on your local Apache server. This is not the default on Apache 2.4. `.htaccess` overrides are enabled with the `AllowOverride` directive.

For example, somewhere in your server config you need something like this:

```
<Directory /path/to/document-root/>
    # Allow access
    Require all granted

    # Allow all htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The default is `AllowOverride None`.

Comment: Pages not opens without .php extension on localhost.

Comment: That would only happen if your PHP file basename also matched the name of a directory. If this is the case then remove the first_condition_ (ie. `!-d`). However, this does assume that `.htaccess` overrides and mod_rewrite is enabled on your local server. `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled by default on Apache. I'll update my answer.